# How to delete some rows in a reation table which I have not an entity?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have three tables in the database:

- TableA(Id, ...)
- TableB(id, ...)
- TableC(IdA, IdB)

I have some records in the TableC

(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,1)
(2,5)

I would like to delete the records in the tableC where IdB is 1 and IdA = 1, so I have to preserve when IdB is associated to anthers rows in TableA.

How I have not an entity of the tableC, I don't have navigation properties in the entities of the TableA and TableB, so I can't use the clear or remove items to do it.

So my question is, in this cases, how could I delete the rows in the tableC?

Thank you.